# Is there a word for an educated person who doesn’t use it?

Tags: single-word-requests

My daughter it doing a report and needs a word for a highly educated person who does not use the education for the greater good of himself/herself or society. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi Donna, Welcome to EL&U. What has she come up with so far?

Comment: Nothing so far. The teacher said they were unable to use the word ‘sloth’. I suggested ‘unemployed ‘ but that isn’t what she was looking for.

Comment: "under-achiever" is a relatively polite and not terribly judgmental way of desribing a person who doesn't employ all their resources to their fullest. It is not precisely tied to education and, in my opinion, more generally used with aptitude underutilized.

Comment: Another, which I am also not submitting as an answer because it just misses, is Dilettante  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dilettante .  It has more of the pejorative sense of  ... er say poorly applied knowledge, but it is more about careless completeness of education that would preclude it being useful even if applied.

Comment: Noun or adjective? Please edit your question to add an example sentence as required for single-word-requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do you call someone who isn't doing their calling in life?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126148/what-do-you-call-someone-who-isnt-doing-their-calling-in-life)

Answer (score -2):

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unproductive)

unproductive:

—not effective in bringing something about: not yielding results, benefits, or profits

Used to merely make an *unbiased statement of productivity* notwithstanding the many possible complex **reasons** for such which may range from a lack of motivation, burnout, or mental depression.